# mongoose return default value if document is missing a key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given schema like this:

```
new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: 'John',
    required: true,
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
  },
})
```

If I happen to have a document in my collection of this shape:

```
{
    color: 'Blue'
}
```

Then the above is exacltly what will be returned. I understand that default is for inserts, but I'd like the missing keys to also get a default value, or at lease be returned with value of `undefined`

When I query for this item, I the name will not be returned at all. I'd like the returned value to be

```
{
    color: 'Blue',
    name: 'John'
}
```

or perhaps this

```
{
    color: 'Blue',
    name: undefined
}
```

It will be so much more readable for the frontend guys.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use that schema to insert documents you always going to have &#39;Jhon&#39; as default name unless you add a different one. You could also use &#39;undefine&#39; as default property, so if you create a new model with an empty name field, it will have undefined value as default.

Comment: I am actually concidering backwards compatibility - If schema changes, than I'd need to run migration to update old items. I'd like to be able to add default return value instead.

Comment: Could you show the query you are using to retriving the documents

Comment: That's what I was thinking hehe, in that case you could run an update in your collection, query all documents without a name and set those with 'default' as a value. db.collection.update({name=""},{$set:{name:"default"}). If field name doesn't exists, just use {} as first parameter to select all documents in the collection. Hope it helps.